# Variable in jquery .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, rotatetransform

So, i have a problem. I want to rotation of the div to be the value of "anVar"

I now have this:

```
function something() {
  $('.class').css('-webkit-transform:rotate('anVar'deg)')
}
```

after that the css should look like this:

```
.class {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(220deg);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try this $('.class').css('-webkit-transform:rotate('+ anVar + 'deg)')

Comment: $('.class').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + anVar + 'deg)')

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add all of the browser prefixes. I like to create an object to handle transforms like so:

```
var transformFn = {
    rotate: function(object, degree) {
        $(object).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });
    }
};
```

To call it:

```
transformFn.rotate($('.class'), 220);
```

---

Calling this function will rotate the object 220 degrees, but calling it again will not rotate it an additional 220 degrees. If you would like to preserve the state (rotate the object from it's current rotation, rather than 0), you could change the rotate function to:

```
rotate: function(object, degree) {
    if ($(object).attr('data-rotation')) {
        degree = parseInt($(object).attr('data-rotation')) + degree;
    }
    $(object).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
        'zoom': 1
    });
    $(object).attr('data-rotation', degree);
}
```